# how many pip packages do one have installed on google colab?

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I can do `!pip list` to see a list of all the packages.

I can do this to count all the sub folders in the `python 3.7` folder:

```py
import os
containing_folder = '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages'


f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(containing_folder):
    f.extend(dirnames)
    break

print('there are', len(f), 'folders in the python 3.7 module')
```

but the number of folders does not equate to the number of modules as there appear to be more files than modules.

So how can i identify all the modules (and not folders) ?
(ie. count all the pip installed folders).

Comment: Why can't you just use the results of running `pip list`?  And why do you care how many modules are installed?

Comment: hi @CryptoFool.   because i would need to manually count each one from the list.  that is essentially my question...   does `!pip list` return a list or can i get the pip list as a **list** ?

Comment: `!pip list | nl` adds numbers.

Comment: @tripleee,  this works, so if one wanted to programmatically get the last value of that list, could that be done ?

Comment: @D.L - yes, should work fine if you use the `subprocess` module to run `pip`.  What  I was trying was the same thing...`pip list | wc -l`.  If you do use `subprocess` to do this, make sure you add `shell=True` as a parameter.  You need to have your command run via a shell so that the pipe will work`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python packages are denoted by the existence of a file named `__init__.py`.  So if you want to count packages in terms of that formal definition, you can just count the number of files you find with this name.  Here's code that will do that:

```
import os
containing_folder = '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages'

f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(containing_folder):
    if '__init__.py' in filenames:
        f.append(os.path.basename(dirpath))

print(f)

print('there are', len(f), 'folders in the python 3.7 module')
```

If you just want to count the number of packages at the first level of a directory, which is probably what you want, here's code that does that:

```
import os
containing_folder = '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages'

r = []
for entity in os.listdir(containing_folder):
    f = os.path.join(containing_folder, entity, '__init__.py')
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(containing_folder, entity)) and os.path.join(entity) and os.path.exists(f):
        r.append(entity)

print(len(r))
```

When I ran this code on one of my Python installs, and compared it against what I get when I do `pip list | wc -l` on that same version of Python, I got almost the same result...`125` for the Python code, `129` for `pip`.

Comment: i think the answer will be something like this, but there appears to be `5729` files when i run the above... which seems to be way to many.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the code is doing what I  say it's doing.  I ran `find . -name "__init__.py" | wc -l` on the same target directory and got the exact same result as what Python gave me.  I also got a number that seemed pretty high.  But I can't think of a way that both the Python code and the `find` command could be getting it wrong in exactly the same way.  Now, if you choose to define what a "package" is differently, then you need another mechanism per that defintion.  That's why I said "count packages in terms of that formal definition".

Comment: I hear what you are saying.  My _"definition of a package"_ is the result of the `!pip list` assuming that it a valid definition...

Comment: I just wrote the list that is generated to a file and took a look at it.  It seems right to me.  Larger packages have a TON of subpackages.  Pandas, for example, has 147 sub-packages.  If you only want the primary modules, you could look for `__init__.py` files at just one level of directory depth, or something like that, or possibly stop when you first find a `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

You could [use `pip` programmatically](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program) (though frankly, finding the documentation for this is a bit daunting).
In theory, you could `import pip` and use its internal APIs to fetch the information you want, but the documentation discourages this, and instead suggests you use `pip` like any non-native external utility.

```
import subprocess

packages = subprocess.run(
    ['pip', 'list'].
    check=True, text=True, capture_output=True)
packagelist = packages.stdout.splitlines()
```

There are many details about `subprocess` which could benefit from a more detailed explanation, but it has been done [many times before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538) Perhaps for this discussion, mainly note that passing the first argument as a list of tokens is required on Unix-like systems when [you want avoid `shell=True` (which you want, when you can)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess).